# Video file to image stream in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, tensorflow, dart, video

I have a video file in my assets folder (like mp4). I want to read that video file as an image stream, like an image stream in the camera package https://pub.dev/documentation/camera/latest/camera/CameraController/startImageStream.html

I want to pass the image to Tflite model.

Something like that:

```
controller = loadVideo('assets/example.mp4');  // how to do that?! 
controller.startImageStream((CameraImage img) {
          Tflite.runPoseNetOnFrame(
              bytesList: img.planes.map((plane) {
                return plane.bytes;
              }).toList(),
              imageHeight: img.height,
              imageWidth: img.width,
              numResults: 1,
              threshold: 0.1,
            ).then((recognitions) {
              // ...
            }
        }
```

I tried to search in the image_picker and video_player packages, but did not find anything.

Comment: I don't get what you want. Why play it as an image stream? Why not just play it as a video?

Comment: Can you share a demo,what exactly you want,

Comment: @Mayb3Not I don't care how it plays, I want the images data, to pass to the Tflite model. Read the images from the video

Comment: @shirshshukla Something exactly like that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJtZWdbsP34&ab_channel=ShaQian But this video is from the camera in real time, I want the same result from a video file

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Comment: @KimHau I made answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is to split the images and save them as files and then send it to the tf model. It's not fast (because you make file and then read it) but it is working, tested on android and it should work on IOS :)

I made a PR in the package [flutter_export_video_frame](https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame), now it have a function in the name of [exportImagesFromFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/export_video_frame/latest/export_video_frame/ExportVideoFrame/exportImagesFromFile.html). It is Returning a Stream of images from video file as `Stream<File>`.

To get the video file from the asset folder I use the following function:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:path/path.dart';

Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
  final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/$path');
  final fileName = basename(path);

  final file = new File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$fileName');
  await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
      .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

  return file;
}
```

And then to move it to the posenet/model, there is a function that gets `File` as input:

```
var results = await Tflite.runPoseNetOnImage(
      path: path,
      numResults: 1,
    );
```

One possible improvement to this method is to make it works only on the RAM (after you read the video, of course)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure you can do that in one of the following ways:

1. Use the [export_video_frame](https://pub.dev/packages/export_video_frame) plugin
2. Use [video_thumbnail](https://pub.dev/packages/video_thumbnail) plugin

You can specify an exact frame by the time parameter.

Comment: export_video_frame I tried and it's making a file for each image and it's very slow because of that. video_thumbnail I think it has returned one image and it also save as file if I not mistaken. Can you show me a code that read a full video to frames and pass it a tflite model (posenet)?

Comment: I would do it if I had enough time, but I am sorry.